# What are the troubleshooting steps to troubleshoot if jquery events are not firing off?

Tags: jquery

If a jquery event is not firing off, what are troubleshooting steps to figure out what causing why the event is not firing off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps I take:

1. Check the error console in your favorite javascript debugger and make sure there are no javascript errors of any kind.  If there are, fix/eliminate them.
2. Make sure your jQuery selectors that install the event handlers are actually working.  You might have the selector not quite right, you might be calling it too early before that object is in the page or before that part of the page has been parsed.
3. Set a breakpoint in the first statement of the event handler to prove to yourself that it's not getting called.
4. Check that you're actually installing the event handler on the right object.  For a mouse click, make sure that nothing is on top of the desired element.
5. Beyond this, it's specific to what type of event you're talking about.  Any further help would need sample code that you've reduced to a jsFiddle that shows what doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

1. first of all make sure the jQuery is loaded
2. check the firebug and see if there are any errors [*follow this link*](http://getfirebug.com/javascript)
3. check whether the elements you are trying to bind the events to are present in the DOM, you can  make it sure by wrapping all jQuery code inside the ready handler like

   `$(document).ready(function{
   });`

   or the short form

   `$(function(){
   });`
4. if you are using multiple javascript libraries like jquery and mootools together there might be a conflict to resolve it there is [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)
5. if you are using visual studio(i dont know if it works else where also) place the key word debugger to stop the execution of the script and proceed step by step